# Move folders if bigger than 2GB

Tags: powershell

I have tried to modify unsuccessfully another script that list correctly folders bigger than 2GB so that it moves them
(I only changed the row  `$fso = New-Object -COM 'Scripting.FileSystemObject'`) :

```
$threshold = 2GB
$fso = Move-Item -path -Destination "C:\Dest\"
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Source\' -Recurse -Directory |  Where-Object {
    $fso.GetFolder($_.FullName).Size -gt $threshold
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution (adapted from https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2468783-ps-script-to-find-folder-1gb-and-move-to-another-folder) ! :

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Source' -Directory | ForEach-Object {

    $Folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -File -Recurse
    $FolderSize = $Folder | Measure-Object -Sum Length

    if ($FolderSize.Sum -gt 2GB) {
        Write-Information -MessageData "$_ is larger than 2GB. Size is $FolderSize" -InformationAction Continue       
        Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\dest'
    }
}
```